# how to prevent kleopatra (or other openpgp tools) from storing your key passphrases

Tags: password, encryption, openpgp

I am trying to use kleopatra to encrypt not just messages but files as well. I have noticed that when decrypting a file, it no longer asks me for the key's pass-phrase. Presumably because the pass-phrase is stored on the computer somewhere. But doesn't this to some extent defeat the purpose of encryption? I want my files to be secure even if someone malicious takes control of it. It seems a little like if when you start your computer up, ubuntu stored the password needed to login to your account and entered it for you automatically.

So how do you prevent kleopatra from storing passwords? And is there some way for me to have piece of mind that a clever hacker won't be able to search my computer and find the passwords they need (i.e. is there some where passphrases are stored? Id like to restrict permission to this file if so)

Comment: Did you try this ? https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdepim/kleopatra/configuration-crypto-operations.html

Comment: following the advice on the site, I had used "gpg_agent" to expire cached pins after 5 seconds. No luck though

Comment: This has worked for me under Win10: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/260890/4780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after quite a bit of digging, I have discovered that the gnome-keyring is the culprit for caching the passwords. The solution is found here

https://confluence.clazzes.org/display/KH/Preventing+Gnome-Keyring+from+caching+GPG+keys+forever